# Why are callbacks callable in Rails model classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails model class like this:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create do
     self.key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
  end

end
```

Why can I call `before_create` here? I expected it to be a method of `ActiveRecord::Base` but it is not. Callbacks are methods of `ActiveRecord::Callbacks`. But why can I call them in a model class without including something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that because `ActiveRecord::Base` does this (or something similar depending on your version of Rails):

```
Base.class_eval do
  #...
  include Callbacks, ActiveModel::Observing, Timestamp
  #...
end
```

So `ActiveRecord::Base` already includes `ActiveRecord::Callbacks` and your class picks up the callbacks by inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 2):

Because ActiveRecord::Base includes it for you. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2135

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are a Module within ActiveRecord that Module is then 'mixed in' to Base which 'Something' extends. Modules/Mixins are kind of like interfaces in some static languages but they also include the implementation of a method rather than just a contract to implement it.