# Findout which mixins are included in Rails classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wondered that I can call `before_create` in a model class altough this method is not in the `ActiveRecord::Base` class. So I learned that this method was [mixed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289088/). But the [documentation says nothing about mixins](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

How can I find out which mixins are included in a Rails class (without looking into the source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I use the [included_modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000472) method in the rails console.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > ActiveRecord::Base.included_modules
 => [ActiveRecord::Aggregations, ActiveRecord::Transactions, <<SNIP>>]
```